# Why Zend Studio doesn't recoqnize my zend server?

Tags: zend-studio

If I try to debug, what I see is this screenshot.

[image]

Basically Zend says that there is no PhP server selected for test project.

And then the auto generated URL which cannot be chang esays http:///

But I GOT a server. And usually this get taken care off automatically.

What should I have done? How do I specify that the http:/// should have been http://localhost/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

**My solution:**

Go to: Preferences > PHP > Servers

1) Delete all the previous servers.

2) Create a new server (maybe similar to the previous... but new).

3) Edit the new server to select the debugger (because in the "creation window" I can't configure it).

[image: Preferences > PHP > Servers]

[image: Preferences > PHP > Servers > Edit]

Go to: Preferences > PHP > Debug

Select the new server

[image: Preferences > PHP > Debug]

Now it works! (at least in my case).

[image: Now it works!]